# Localize WP7 application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, localization

I was looking into ways to localize an application. I saw this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=vs.92).aspx but I was wondering if it would be possible to use a different language than the one the user sets on his phone. Let's say that the user sets his language to English, but I want my app to display an interface in spanish if the user chooses so using some listbox.
Do you have any articles regarding this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and I do it with my Google Reader client gReadie using the following code, which I call on application start and resume.

```
public static void SetLanguage() {
    CultureInfo c = null;
    switch (ViewModel.UserSettings.Language) {
    case Language.Default:
        break;
    case Language.English:
        c = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        break;
    case Language.Chinese:
        c = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
        break;
    case Language.French:
        c = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        break;
    case Language.German:
        c = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        break;
    }

    if (c != null) {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = c;
        ApplicationStrings.Culture = c;
    }
}
```

So basically I have a dropdown in my settings which is bound to a languge enum and allows the user to choose their phone language (default) or one of the supported lanaguages.
Then on app start I set the language of the UI thread and of my ApplicationStrings resource file to match their selection.

Comment: It is just a regular Resource File. I assume the tutorial you were looking at uses them, it is the standard way to localize in .NET / Silverlight. So there is the english ApplocationString.rex, each language has an ApplicationStrings.de-DE.resx in the same folder.